# Sort string array with exceptions Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort an array of string alphabetically, but with an exception that some elements should always be sorted first and second in the array. Here are the elements of the array:

`["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"]`

I want it sorted alphabetically, but with `zebra` always first and `cat` always second, so after sorted it should look like:

`["zebra", "cat", "bird", "dog", "elephant"]`

This is how I have approached it:

```
    let animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"]
    
    animals = animals.sorted(by: { first, second in
        if first == "zebra" {return true}
        if first == "cat" {return true}
        return first < second
    })
```

It returns zebra first, but not cat second

Comment: I suggest move the ones you don't want to start to a separate array. and then story the array.

Comment: @SathyaBaman there should be a way using the sorted method

Answer (score 1):

The closure you pass to `sorted(by:)` should return `true` whenever the elements are in ascending order, and `false` otherwise. You can’t tell if the elements are in ascending order unless you check both the first value and the second. That’s why returning `true` whenever the first value is “zebra” or “cat” won’t work—not all your bases are covered.

One solution would be to use a `switch` statement to specify the comparison logic depending on the values you’re looking at:

```swift
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"].sorted {
    switch ($0, $1) {
    case ("zebra", "cat"): // zebra is before cat
        return true
    case ("cat", "zebra"): // cat is not before zebra
        return false
    case ("cat", _), ("zebra", _): // zebra/cat are before everything
        return true
    case (_, "cat"), (_, "zebra"): // zebra/cat are not after anything
        return false
    case let (lhs, rhs): // alphabetical order
        return lhs < rhs
    }
}
// ["zebra", "cat", "bird", "dog", "elephant"]
```

If this looks a little overengineered, that’s because it is. Covering all your bases like this is hard, so I would definitely recommend taking a look at your use case and considering whether you really need to do it this way. If you can get away with something simpler, that’s probably your best bet. For example:

```swift
let animals = ["zebra", "cat"] + ["dog", "bird", "elephant"].sorted()
// ["zebra", "cat", "bird", "dog", "elephant"]
```

Or, if the `animals` array can’t be modified, another option would be to hard-code the exceptions:

```swift
let exceptions = ["zebra", "cat"]
let otherAnimals = animals.filter { !exceptions.contains($0) }.sorted()
let sortedResult = exceptions + otherAnimals
// ["zebra", "cat", "bird", "dog", "elephant"]
```

**Edit:** A now-removed comment questioned the reliability of the `switch` statement method. I tested it with every possible order of the `animals` array, and it returned the correct result every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that enums compare by case declaration order first, and then lexicographically by payload values. This feature was implemented in Swift 5.3, see

- [SE-0266 Synthesized Comparable conformance for enum types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0266-synthesized-comparable-for-enumerations.md)

If we define an enumeration type with "zebra" and "cat" cases ordered first

```
enum AnimalOrder: Comparable {
    case zebra
    case cat
    case other(String)
    
    init(animal: String) {
        switch animal {
        case "zebra": self = .zebra
        case "cat": self = .cat
        default: self = .other(animal)
        }
    }
}
```

then the desired sorting is simply achieved with

```
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"]
let sorted = animals.sorted(by: {
    AnimalOrder(animal: $0) < AnimalOrder(animal: $1)
})

print(sorted) // ["zebra", "cat", "bird", "dog", "elephant"]
```

This approach can easily be extended to cover more “special cases.”

Answer (score -1):

The answer you're going for is:

```
var animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"]

animals = animals.sorted(by: { first, second in
    if first == "cat" && second == "zebra" {return false;}
    if second == "cat" && first == "zebra" {return true;}                          
    if first == "zebra" || first == "cat" {return true;}
    if second == "zebra" || second == "cat" {return false;}
    
    return first < second
})
```

You could even try calling `animals.shuffle()` before you sort to check that the sorting works regardless of input ordering.

This is the more readable way to do it, although potentially less efficient:

```
var animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "zebra", "elephant"]

animals = animals.sorted();

var wordIndex:Int = animals.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "zebra"})!;
animals.insert(animals.remove(at: wordIndex), at: 0);

wordIndex = animals.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "cat"})!;
animals.insert(animals.remove(at: wordIndex), at: 1);
```

Or if you want a more generalized version:

```
 func sortAndPrepend(inputArr: [String], prependWords: [String]) -> [String]{
    var array = inputArr.sorted();
    
    var wordIndex:Int;
    for i in 0...prependWords.count-1 {
        wordIndex = array.firstIndex(where: {$0 == prependWords[i]}) ?? -1;
        if (wordIndex != -1) {
            array.insert(array.remove(at: wordIndex), at: i);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```